# can't retrieve distant data with hasManyThrough method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

For the sake of example I have this setup:

```
item_model
    id - integer
    name - string

collected_item
    id - integer
    model_id - integer


posts
    id - integer
    collected_item_id - integer
    title - string
```

I want to retrieve all the posts regarding an item_model through the collected_item model.

So I set the relation in the item_model like this:

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'App\Collected_item');
    }
```

but then how do I retrieve the posts? Since I am looking for models by name I tried like this to no avail:

```
$posts = Item_model::where('model_name', 'LIKE', $q . '%')->posts();
```

or

```
$posts = Item_model::where('model_name', 'LIKE', $q . '%')->posts()->get();
```

Error returned:

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had it working. This is the correct relationship in Item_model

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'App\Collected_item', 'model_id', 'collected_item_id', 'id' );
    }
```

Where the third argument is the foreign key in the intermediate model, the fourth the foreign key on the Post Model and the fifth is the local (item_model) key.

After that WITHOUT HAVING TO PREEMPTIVELY load posts I could do:

```
$item= Item_model::find(220); (an item which I know has related posts)

$posts = $item->posts;

dd($posts);
```

This returns the posts, so it's not true that you have to load them before like other suggested, the hasManyThrough method is in charge of retrieving the posts.

Answer (score 0):

try the "with" method..

```
$posts = Item_model::with('posts')->where('model_name', 'LIKE', $q . '%')->get();
```

to get only the item_models where a posts exists use the "has" method

```
$posts = Item_model::has('posts')->where('model_name', 'LIKE', $q . '%')->get();
```

Comment: it kind of works but this way retrieves all the item_models regardless of them having related posts or not. I need to retrieve only the posts not the models.

Comment: if you want only the item_models that have posts you have to use the Has method, like this..

    $posts = Item_model::has('posts')->where('model_name', 'LIKE', $q . '%')->get();

Comment: no, I want the posts not the models and that should be possible with hasManyThrough as per laravel docs. BUT it doesn't work.

Comment: we dont your model setup, but maybe you have to set the reverse realition too in the Posts model for the ItemModel.. and get it so:

$posts = Posts::has('itemModel')->where('model_name', 'LIKE', $q . '%')->get();

Comment: I don't think so, because it's the model that has many related posts through collected_item not the inverse.

Comment: is it only one model that get returned on the search?.. then get the result $test = $posts->first(); $test->posts() for getting all posts from the "model"..

Comment: otherise map it .. $postsArray = ""; Item_model::has('posts')->where('model_name', 'LIKE', $q . '%')->get()->each(function($itemmodel) use ($postsArray) { $postArray[] = $itemmodel->posts()});

Comment: I don't get how this makes sense: $test = $posts->first(); $test->posts() .. where are you getting the model info here?

Comment: This should be a matter of $item_model->posts and that's it, but how do you do it with query builder ?!

Comment: you cant get the posts directly with your current setup.. if you want the posts that in the itemmodels you have to set the reverse releatioship too.. then Posts::has('itemmodel')->get() for all posts with an itemmodel. .. for the actual code you can do it like that http://kopy.io/2IwQK

Comment: what would be the inverse of the hasManyThrough relation? Doing like you suggested returns an empty collection. Only if I add ->with('posts') to the query will return the posts but then this is not retrieved through hasManyThrough for what I know.

Comment: have you tried a jeft join on the posts model? withouth realitionship methods..? then you have the post with the item_model in the same row.. if multiple posts by collection_item then group them

Comment: I already know how to retrieve the model with posts with other methods and it's working. What I'm trying to understand is why the hasManyThrough method is not working. I did everything as in laravel docs to no avail.

Comment: you cant get it directly only with the realationship like you figured out a few posts earlier.. with('posts') .. $data->posts for the realtiondata.. with $data->posts() you fetch them new..

Comment: Did You see laravel docs? It says: set The hasManyThrough relationship then You can access posts as easy as $item->posts;

Comment: exactly.. but you have to traverse like my examples.. http://kopy.io/6Eb5M

Comment: you cant get them withouth the prevoius model instance.. in your case item_model.. the posts get fetched in the realtionship attribute.. $item->posts..

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. You should be able to get all the posts related to item passing the item Id. If You load the posts with query builder then what is this hasManyThrough relationship good for? For example you should select item id 1 and then get the posts with $item->posts; not load posts before! It's the $item->posts; that is in charge of retrieving the posts.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to declare the name of the method before making the get call

Item_model::with('posts')->get();

Comment: it kind of works but this way retrieves all the item_models regardless of them having related posts or not. I need to retrieve only the posts not the models.

Comment: whats your version of laravel?

Comment: it's version 5.1.28 (LTS)

Comment: ->where('model_name', 'LIKE', '%'. $q . '%') try adding the % at front too, let me know

Comment: why? that would retrieve only more models with the term in between two wildcards not the posts

Comment: ye, got confused what you mean by related posts?

Comment: please take a look at the hasManyThrough method in Laravel docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through